# Installation of Fisheye on ubuntu server is complete but hostname:8060 not responding, what's wrong?

Tags: fisheye

After jira installation using the mod_proxy setup to access projects.mysite.com/jira, Which is perfectly working fine. I wanted to install fisheye on same system to access GIT repository on jira.

While Installing fisheye server was started from the console. but i can't access hostip:8060 or hostname:8060. I checked the service running shown below, 
Can anyone help?

```
amer@projects:~$ sudo ps -ef | grep fisheye
root     13449 13448  5 02:04 pts/0    00:02:28 /usr/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfisheye.library.path= -Dfisheye.inst=/opt/fecru-2.7.8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/fecru-2.7.8/lib/endorsed -jar /opt/fecru-2.7.8/fisheyeboot.jar run
amer     13680 13302  0 02:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto fisheye
```

Comment: Can you run: "sudo netstat -pant |grep 8060" ?  That'll show if there's any process listening on port 8060.  If that doesn't return anything, run "sudo netstat -pant |grep java".

Comment: Yes, here's the result:

amer@projects:~$ sudo netstat -pant | grep 8060
tcp6       0      0 :::8060                 :::*                    LISTEN      13449/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by setting apache mod_proxy. Easy steps are to make site file on apache2/site-advisors dir such as fisheye.mysite.com and configure its ProxyReverse on http://localhost/8060. You can change fisheye installation config.xml For more information visit Atlassian Administration section of Fisheye. I'm running two applications on same server such as Jira and Fisheye so i needed to configure both to access using proxy. For better understanding visit link: http://www.antelink.com/blog/tutorial-secure-installation-fisheye-77.html